# Query Avro Schema using Beam SQL

Tags: java, apache-beam, beam-sql

I'm trying to read avro files with Apache Beam and use Beam SQL to transform the data.

I'm still new in Beam and Java. Here's my simple code:

```
public class BeamSQLReadAvro {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        /* Schema definition */
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("data/RATE_CODE/RATE_CODE.avsc"));

        /* Create record/row */
        PCollection<GenericRecord> records = p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).from("data/RATE_CODE/*.avro"));

        /* SQL Transform */
        records.apply("SQL Transform 01",SqlTransform.query("SELECT RCODE,RNAME,RDESC FROM PCOLLECTION LIMIT 10"))

        /* Print output */
               .apply("Output",
                      MapElements.via(
                        new SimpleFunction<Row, Row>() {
                          @Override
                          public Row apply(Row input) {
                            System.out.println("PCOLLECTION: " + input.getValues());
                            return input;
                          }
                        }
                      )
               );
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

it gives me error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema
```

I don't understand, I have defined variable called schema. Any pointers here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are two types of schemas in your pipeline - Avro and Beam schemas.  Avro schema is used to parse your Avro input records, but for SQL transform you are supposed to use rows with Beam schema. To do this, `AvroIO` provides an option `withBeamSchemas(boolean)`, which should be set to `true` in your case, like:

```
AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).withBeamSchemas(true).from("data/RATE_CODE/*.avro")
```